# How to run mrjob library python map reduce in ubuntu standalone local hadoop cluster

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

I went through documentation and it says it is meant for aws, gcp. But they are also using it internally somehow right. So, there should be a way to make it run in our own locally created hadoop cluster in our own virtual box

some code for understanding how mrjob is used in code :-

```
class MovieSimilar(MRJob):
 def mapper_parse_input(self, key, line):
    (userID, movieID, rating, timestamp) = line.split('\t')
    yield  userID, (movieID, float(rating))
    ..........
    ..........
if __name__ == '__main__':
  MovieSimilar.run()
```

With hadoop streaming jar and normal python codes I am able to run python codes.But mrjob isn't accepting data-set location from command line and giving more than 2 values required to unpack. And that error is because it is unable to take date set given -input flag

The shell command I am using :-

```
bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-
streaming.jar \
-file /<path_to_mapper>/MovieSimilar.py \
-mapper /<path_to_mapper>/MovieSimilar.py \
-reducer /<path_to_reducer>/MovieSimilar.py  \
-input daily/<dataset-file>.csv \
-output daily/output
```

Note:- daily is my hdfs directory where datasets and result of programs get stored

**Error message I am receiving :- more than 2 values required to unpack**

Comment: With hadoop streaming jar and normal python codes I am able to run python codes.But mrjob isn't accepting data-set location from command line and giving more than 2 values required to unpack. And that error is because it is unable to take date set given -input flag

Comment: Considering we cannot see your code or errors, it's hard to help with that

Comment: Actually, I am expecting an hadoop and python map reduce expert to answer the question. Because my question is staight forward and has nothing to do with code. I am speaking about shell scripting here

Comment: Once again, we don't know what command you have or the error message returned to you, but the answer to the original question is yes, and "2 values to unpack" is not related to shell scripting, it's a specific python error, so please show your code

Comment: I have added the python code for reference . I just want to know how to run this in an ubuntu hadoop  cluster locally setup

Comment: And what command are you using to run the job? What does your input file look like? Based on the error, some line of your input file does not have 4 columns... Also, why not use Pyspark if you simply want to process a TSV file?

Comment: By the way, your mapper function needs to be actually called `mapper` https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/quickstart.html#writing-your-first-job

Comment: I have added the shell command which I am using to execute , and my code personally has 0 errors . It is executing totally fine when running in normal machine or a single node. The issue is with my shell command. I dont know anyother shell command to run this file

Comment: It tells you the command right here https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/runners.html#running-on-your-own-hadoop-cluster

Comment: If you want to use hdfs files, read this section https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/quickstart.html#running-your-job-different-ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> says it is meant for aws, gcp

Those are examples. It is not *meant* for those. Notice the `-r local` and `-r hadoop` flags for running a job

https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/runners.html#running-on-your-own-hadoop-cluster

> there should be a way to make it run in our own locally created hadoop cluster in our own virtual box

Setup your `HADOOP_HOME`, and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` xml files to point at the cluster you want to run the code against, then using the `-r hadoop` runner flag, it'll find and run your code using the hadoop binary and hadoop-streaming jar file

> `more than 2 values required to unpack`. And that error is because it is unable to take date set given -input flag

Can't see your input, but this line would cause that error if there were less than three tabs on any line (and you don't need parentheses left of the equals)

```
(userID, movieID, rating, timestamp) = line.split('\t')
```

I suggest testing your code using the local/inline runner first

> The shell command I am using :-

> `bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop- streaming.jar`

Mrjob will build and submit that for you.

You only need to run `python MovieSimilar.py` with your input files